# How to search the random words from a phrase using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

My orginal Pname in the table 'english' is "The Digital Santa Monica Mug".If users try to search using "Digital Mug", its not returning productwith the pname containing digital mug .

am using this query:

```
select * 
from english 
where((pname like '%$val%' 
       or  desp1 like '%$search%' 
       or pid like '%$search%' $key_value) 
      and warehouse=0 and cid !=49) 
group by pid;
```

Comment: user - Can you try to describe this better?  It seems `pname` is a field of the table `english` but whats with the PHP variables?  `$val`, `$search`, `$key_value` ??

Comment: They are value from the forms... Thanks i have implemented Gaurav query and its working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `pname like '%".implode('%', explode(' ', $val))."%'` instead of `pname like '%$val%'`

In this case order will matter. Means `Digital Mug` will give you result but `MUG Digital` won't.

Comment: what about `'%' . str_replace(' ', '%', $val) . '%')`? ;) I'd also advise to replace `%` with `\%` and `_` with `\_` in `$val` before putting it into the query. And don't forget about sql injections...

Answer (score 1):

You could split up the input value into two different words.  In order to do this, do

```
$term_array = explode(" ", $val);
```

Now, $term_array will hold both words separately, and you can run queries on the words individually.  For example, you could go through the query twice, and run the same query on the single words.   However, doing this would result in duplicates (and likely some unnecessary results). You could probably think of some kind of query using the two separated words that would yield better results, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use full text searches for that

The thing is not working as `The Digital Santa Monica Mug` when searched as 
`Digital Mug` will be taken as `'%Digital Mug%'` which tries to match a value having `Digital Mug` having words before and after.

```
Eg : THE Digital Mug Paradise
```

Such a text will be matched.

So try MYSQL FULL TEXT SEARCH for that

[FULL TEXT SEARCH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Answer (score 1):

Either what The C Man advised (split the search phrase and search for every word), or fulltext search.

---

For "splitting words" method, I'd advise to:

- use regular expressions for splitting, something like
  `preg_match_all('#[a-zA-Z0-9]+#', $text, $words)`;
  you don't need to
  search for symbols like "$", do you?
- write a function that would generate `where` clause for you.

Function for generating `where` clause might look like this:

```
function generateFilter(array $fields, array $words) {
    // prepare $word for putting into SQL statement
    foreach ( $words as &$word ) {
        // ensure that wildcard characters are used as regular characters
        $word = str_replace('%', '\\%', $word);
        $word = str_replace('_', '\\_', $word);
        // prevent SQL injections
        $word = mysql_real_escape_string($word);
    }
    unset($word);
    // generate filter
    $filter = array();
    foreach ( $words as $word ) {
        $wordFilter = array();
        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
            $wordFilter[] = "{$field} like '%$word%'";
        }
        $filter[] = implode(' or ', $wordFilter);
    }
    $filter = '(' . implode(') and (', $filter) . ')';
    return $filter;
}
$filter = generateFilter(
    array('name', 'surname', 'address'),
    array('john', 'doe')
);
echo $filter;
```

Result:

```
(name like '%john%' or surname like '%john%' or address like '%john%') and
(name like '%doe%' or surname like '%doe%' or address like '%doe%')
```

If you use prepared statements (which is highly advised), this function would be a bit more complicated, as resulting string would have placeholders for variables, while $words would be put into some array of variables that have to be bound to prepared statement.

---

"Splitting words" method works for small strings and small amounts of data. If you have huge amounts of data and/or large strings, consider using fulltext search. It does not require to split search phrase, though it has some limitations - it needs fulltext index on columns that are used for searching (IIRC, you can create index on multiple columns and then use fulltext search on all indexed columns at the same time, i.e., you don't have to search every column spearately), it has minimal length of keyword and it might give non-strict results, e.g., sometimes only 3 of 5 keywords might appear in result. Though, it gives relevance of every result - results that are closer to search terms will have higher relevance. This is useful for sorting results by relevance.

While creating index may seem to be an "extra work" for you, it will allow DBMS to perform the search faster than without index.

Comment: You should change the order of `str_replace` and `mysql_real_escape_string`. Otherwise a `%` will first become `\%` by `str_replace` and then `\\%` by `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @Gumbo, it might seem to be wrong, though it does work - tested it from both PHP with `mysql_query()` and from MySQL console client. Value in DB - `'viens%divi'`, `where` caluse - `where str like '%viens\\%divi%'`.

Comment: @Gumbo, from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html - "*Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\\n”. To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.*". So, although `'\%'` works, it *should* be written as `'\\%'`.

Answer (score 0):

To construct query:

```
$split = explode(" ", $val);
$qry_pname = "pname LIKE '%".implode("%' or pname LIKE '%", $split)."'%";

$qry = "
SELECT * 
   FROM english 
WHERE( $qry_pname
       or  desp1 like '%$search%' 
       or pid like '%$search%' $key_value) 
      and warehouse=0 and cid !=49) 
group by pid;
";
```